# Change xml element/tag name using XmlSlurper or XmlParser

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper

I have an xml that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Samples>
  <Sample>
     <Name>
        Sample1
     </Name>
     <Date>
        01/20/2016
     </Date>
  </Sample>
</Samples>
```

I want to simply change the tag name from "Samples" to "SampleList". How will I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`replaceNode`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.html#replaceNode(groovy.lang.Closure)) can be used to rename the node as below:

```
def xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Samples>
  <Sample>
     <Name>
        Sample1
     </Name>
     <Date>
        01/20/2016
     </Date>
  </Sample>
</Samples>
'''

def result = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

result.replaceNode { 
    'SampleList' it.children() 
}

groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(result)
```

`replaceNode` takes a closure as method parameter which delegates to a builder. Specifically in this case the node is replaced instead of appending it to main document. `'SampleList' it.children()` is similar to `'SampleList(it.children())'`.

Parsed xml's root element being `Samples` (which needs replacement), `replaceNode` was directly done on the `result`.

Comment: hi @dmahapatro, could you explain how replaceNode works? becuase you did not specify what name that you want to be replaced but the code works. Thanks :)